# Will a USA entry refusal affect my working visa application to Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, uk-citizens, hong-kong, working-holiday

I was refused entry on arrival in the USA, for trying to enter on a tourist visa when I intended to work for three months. The company had instructed me to do this. I know I was an idiot but I really wanted the job and didn't appreciate the consequences. I am 19 and now have a 5-year ban from the States. I have been offered a job in Hong Kong on a working holiday visa. The question about visa rejection is not on the form but I have a stamp in my passport.

Does anyone know if this affect my application please. I am a British citizen.

Comment: They will see the stamp, so they may take it into their consideration process.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear until you edit to specify whether you are applying to HK, Taiwan or China. Also please tell us your nationality.

Comment: Sorry. I am British and it's to HK. Thanks for all of your comments. This is a genuine question as I just don't know if this will affect my application. I have emailed the Embassey but they say they cannot comment on individual cases. Guess I will just have to apply and see. I just wondered if there was a definite answer. Thank you all.

Comment: Close-vote retracted. Let me see if I can put in a useful answer now...

Answer (score 3):

It may. Or may not. In general the golden rule is to not provide more info than asked but also not to withhold any information or even appear to do so. You might consider getting a new passport but to a visa-officer that typically raises more questions than it gets out of the way, so I would avoid that. Also note that there is an annual quota of 1000 for UK citizens so it might be just bad luck should you be refused. That being said, good luck! Do give us an update when you reveive an answer!

Older version of my answer, now outdated given OP edit:

STOP! Stop what you are doing right now and get your own research going. You *might* be getting SCAMMED. Do not rely on any company or advisor.

First, I do not know of a "working holiday visa" for going to China. It is not listed on the [list of Chinese visa types on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#Types_of_Chinese_Visas) There is exactly [one website](http://www.anyworkanywhere.com/whv_cn.html) which results high on Google talking about such a thing and besides the horrible make of the website, they seem absolutely unprofessional in not making a distinction between China and Taiwan. In fact there is [such a program for Taiwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Taiwan#Working_Holiday_Visa), not China. ([Programs for China are only considerations for now.](http://china.embassy.gov.au/bjng/WorkandHolidaysc462FAQ.html#13.%20Will%20Australians%20be%20able%20to%20apply%20for%20a%20Work%20and%20Holiday%20visa%20to%20China?)) There also exists one for [Hong Kong](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/working_holiday_scheme.html) but then mind you will be working in Hong Kong only, not in China, which you should see as a separate country for the purposes here.

Given the story of how you got that ugly stamp in your passport, you should be a lot more careful in terms of what companies advice you trust.